# why is realm.classToTable count 0 when I get instance of realm object in Android

Tags: realm

I have created my own realm db and I set configuration to  new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).name("mydb.realm").build();
realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);

The classToTable count is 0 and count of rows in the table is also 0. Can someone let me know what am I missing. Thanks.

Comment: Same question on github https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2287 . Conversation is going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you created your models as subsclasses of `RealmObject`?
Follow sample to create some records in db:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(context);

// Define model
public class Dog extends RealmObject {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    // ... Generated getters and setters ...
}

// Create object
Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.setName("Rex");
dog.setAge("1");

// Persist
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealm(dog);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: Thank you. I did the same. All my classes are extending RealmObject. Still everytime in my activity the findAll query on my class is returning 0 results. classToTable is 0 but once I add data using Transaction the classToTable is getting updated but only for that session. If app is relaunched classToTable is again zero.